# Can I prevent update or delete on an Oracle DB?

Tags: database, oracle, readonly

I have to implement a financial application. One of the acceptance criteria is:

> *"The data may never change."*

Therefore I need to prevent `update` and `delete` operations on the database, because it will be deployed on machines owned and administrated by the customer.

Is this even possible? Maybe with triggers? If not, are there any other databases that can prevent `update` and `delete`?

Comment: Oracle uses grants. Just don't give those grants to the user of your application. In addition you can write triggers to do this. But I'd check that acceptance criterium, because you'd want to change data in some occasions, and maybe keep a history of previous versions of that data for auditing purposes. Even if you keep everything in one table, you may want to set some 'most recent' flag to make your queries performant, so please do think this over before you build a solution that comes to a grinding halt within a year.

Comment: Anyway, that prevents editing through common use. There is always somebody [going to be able to edit your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290692/prevent-delete-update-for-tables-by-even-superadmin-dba?rq=1), which is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: This should be implemented on application level. Note, as an administrator you can bypass/disable almost every constraint. If administrators are excluded from such limitation use simple GRANTS or triggers or (more advanced and more expensive) Oracle Virtual Private Database, resp.  Fine Grained Access Control

Comment: Is this a particular subset of data? How is the data going to be loaded? And is this "Cannot be modified once it has been inserted by the application"?

Comment: The criterion applies to all stored data. Reading must be possible, but once the data are persisted, they may not change.

Comment: I don't understand why to deploy a DB to client but deny the client to do any DML? Mybe you want the client not to do any DDL (ALTER....) ? this has more sense. Anyway you can 1)open DB in Read Only so nobody can change anything in DB or 2)you can select MAX DDL time from dba_objects and compare that DDL with current and if current is > than MAX then definitely somebody did a DDL

Comment: You are right, the client shall not have any privileges on the database. But if he manages to get the credentials out of the application, I am legally obliged to prevent change to the data. Therefore even the application may only have `INSERT` and `SELECT` privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It turns out to be impossible.**

There is no way to grant an `INSERT` privilege without allowing to `UPDATE`. As I understand it, the `INSERT` privilege is interpreted as *may alter data of that table*.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is via roles, such as a query role. Grant select on the list of tables to that role, and grant that role to the user of your application.  You can of course create others such as an admin role with update and delete privileges, to be granted later on when needed.

Example:

```
CREATE ROLE FIN_APP_INS_SEL_ROLE;                                   
GRANT INSERT, SELECT on <table1> to FIN_APP_INS_SEL_ROLE;
GRANT INSERT, SELECT on <table2> to FIN_APP_INS_SEL_ROLE;
GRANT CONNECT, FIN_APP_INS_SEL_ROLE to <app_user>;
```

You can also make tablespaces read only,

```
ALTER TABLESPACE <name> READ ONLY;
```

or the entire database read only.

```
ALTER DATABASE OPEN READ ONLY;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but how would I configure a role, that can `INSERT` but not `UPDATE` or `DELETE`?

Comment: You just give the role INSERT privileges only and not the others e.g. grant INSERT on <table> to <special_insert_role>;

Comment: No, `INSERT` and `SELECT`.